# How to update another instance of a model when I save new data using CoreData in another view

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am building a simple Quiz iOS application which uses CoreData to store the questions that are used in the quiz.

I have my home screen view which navigates to "Play Demo Quiz", "Play My Quiz" and "Add New Question" views.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var quizViewModel = QuizViewModel(categoryIndex: 1)

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Text("Quizzy").font(.largeTitle).bold()
            Spacer()
            NavigationLink(
                destination: MainQuizView(categoryIndex: 0),
                label: {
                    DefaultNavigationLinkLabel(labelText: "Play Demo Quiz")
                }
            )
            NavigationLink(
                destination: MainQuizView(categoryIndex: 1),
                label: {
                    DefaultNavigationLinkLabel(labelText: "Play My Quiz").padding()
                }
            )
            NavigationLink(
                destination: AddQuestionView(),
                label: {
                    DefaultNavigationLinkLabel(labelText: "Add New Questions")
                }
            )
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Quizzy"), displayMode: .inline)
    }.onAppear(){
        quizViewModel.deleteAllQuestions()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "launchedBefore")
        if(!quizViewModel.checkIfLaunchedBefore()){
            quizViewModel.savePresetDemoQuestions()
            print("First time.")
        }else{
            print("Launched before.")
        }
    }
}}
```

Each and every one of those views has its own QuizViewModel which has a QuizModel

```
class QuizViewModel : ObservableObject{

private let categoryIndex: Int
@Published private var quizModel: QuizModel
private(set) var currentQuestion: Question?

init(categoryIndex: Int) {
    self.categoryIndex = categoryIndex
    self.quizModel = QuizModel(categoryIndex: categoryIndex)
    currentQuestion = Question()
    if(getQuestionCount() != 0){
        getCurrentQuestion()
    }
}

func checkAnswer(answerIndex: Int) -> Bool{
    quizModel.checkAnswer(answerIndex: answerIndex)
}

func getCurrentQuestion() -> Bool{
    do{
        try currentQuestion = quizModel.getCurrentQuestion()
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}

func getQuestionCount() -> Int{
    quizModel.getQuestionCount()
}

func getCurrentQuestionIndex() -> Int{
    quizModel.getCurrentQuestionIndex()
}

func getUserScore() -> Int{
    quizModel.getUserScore()
}

func restartGame(){
    quizModel.restartGame(categoryIndex: categoryIndex)
    getCurrentQuestion()
}

func deleteAllQuestions(){
    quizModel.deleteAllQuestions()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "launchedBefore")
}

func savePresetDemoQuestions(){
    self.quizModel.savePresetDemoQuestions()
    restartGame()
}

func saveQuestion(questionText: String, answers: [String], correctAnswerIndex: Int){
    self.quizModel.saveQuestion(questionText: questionText, answers: answers, correctAnswerIndex: correctAnswerIndex, categoryIndex: 1)
    restartGame()
}

func saveDummyQuestion(){
    quizModel.saveDummyQuestion()
    restartGame()
}

// Utility functions
func checkIfLaunchedBefore() -> Bool{
    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore  {
        return launchedBefore
    } else {
        print("First launch, setting UserDefault.")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    }
    return false
}}
```

This is the QuizModel

```
struct QuizModel{
private var questions: [Question] = []
private let categoryIndex: Int
private var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 0
private let coreDataManager = CoreDataManager()

var userScore = 0;

init(categoryIndex: Int){
    self.categoryIndex = categoryIndex
    loadQuestions(categoryIndex: categoryIndex)
}

enum QuizQuestionSetError: Error{
    case outOfQuestions;
}

func getCurrentQuestion() throws -> Question{
    guard currentQuestionIndex < questions.count else{
        throw QuizQuestionSetError.outOfQuestions
    }
    
    return questions[currentQuestionIndex]
}

mutating func checkAnswer(answerIndex: Int) -> Bool{
    var isCorrect: Bool = false
    
    if(answerIndex == questions[currentQuestionIndex].correctAnswerIndex){
        userScore += 1
        isCorrect = true
    }
    currentQuestionIndex += 1
    return isCorrect
}

func getQuestionCount() -> Int{
    questions.count
}

func getCurrentQuestionIndex() -> Int{
    currentQuestionIndex
}

func getUserScore() -> Int{
    userScore
}

mutating func loadQuestions(categoryIndex: Int){
    self.questions = coreDataManager.fetchQuestions().filter{ question in
        question.categoryIndex == categoryIndex
    }.shuffled()
}

mutating func restartGame(categoryIndex: Int){
    loadQuestions(categoryIndex: categoryIndex)
    self.currentQuestionIndex = 0
    self.userScore = 0
}

func saveQuestion(questionText: String, answers: [String], correctAnswerIndex: Int, categoryIndex: Int){
    coreDataManager.saveQuestion(questionText: questionText, answers: answers, correctAnswerIndex: correctAnswerIndex, categoryIndex: categoryIndex)
    
}

mutating func savePresetDemoQuestions(){
    guard let encodedDemoQuestions = self.readDemoJsonFile(forName: "DemoQuestions") else{
        return
    }
    
    if let decodedDemoQuestions = self.parse(jsonData: encodedDemoQuestions){
        for demoQuestion in decodedDemoQuestions {
            coreDataManager.saveQuestion(questionText: demoQuestion.questionText,
                                         answers: demoQuestion.answers,
                                         correctAnswerIndex: demoQuestion.correctAnswerIndex,
                                         categoryIndex: demoQuestion.categoryIndex)
        }
        print(decodedDemoQuestions.count)
    }
    print("Updating questions.....")
    self.loadQuestions(categoryIndex: categoryIndex)
    
}
// MARK: - Utility Methods
private func readDemoJsonFile(forName name: String) -> Data? {
    do{
        if let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "json"),
           let jsonData = try String(contentsOfFile: bundlePath).data(using: .utf8){
            return jsonData
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
    return nil
}

private func parse(jsonData: Data) -> [QuestionStruct]?{
    do {
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([QuestionStruct].self, from: jsonData)
        return decodedData
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}

func saveDummyQuestion(){
    saveQuestion(questionText: "AAAAAAAAAAA", answers: ["N","B","C","D"], correctAnswerIndex: 2, categoryIndex: 1)
}

func deleteAllQuestions(){
    print("\n\n\n Deleted")
    coreDataManager.deleteAllQuestions()
}}
```

So how can I tell my instanced "Play My Quiz" model to reload his questions when a question gets saved in "AddQuestionView" using another instance of that model?
The full project can be accessed here if neccessary: https://github.com/MateoA/Quizzy

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry for the messy question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Observe/Listen for CoreData changes you need to use the [`@FetchRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest) wrapper that was made for SwiftUI in the `View` or use the traditional [FetchedRequestController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller) wrapped in an `ObservableObject` (since you have a CoreData Manager)

The it is a lot of code but the [CoreData Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller) has a good tutorial on how to create it wrapped in a TableView. The big difference is that instead of updating the TableView you will update a variable in the ObservableObject.

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    //Update an @Published variable here
}
```

[Tutorial Combo Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-U-4Zon6dbE)

Also, you should Observe the `QuizViewModel` and pass it on [appropriately](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

```
//In the ContentView
@StateObject var quizViewModel = QuizViewModel(categoryIndex: 1)
    //Initialize the Views that need the model like this
AddQuestionView().environmentObject(quizViewModel)

//All Views that need the Model
struct AddQuestionView:View{
   @EnvironmentObject var quizViewModel = QuizViewModel
  //...
}
```

You might be able to Maximize the SwiftUI advantages if you look over the [Apple SwiftUI tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/)